# Twilio Studio: In-Call Menu after connecting two calls?

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to complete the following in Twilio Studio. From a high level after an API request we place a call to our team and then a customer. At the end of the call (The customer should always hangup first) I want to bring up a DTMF survey. However, it is possible that the customer may not hang up first and to handle this event I'd like to implement a way that the employee can bring up the DTMF survey. Is this possible?

***Studio Flow:***

1. Request comes in from API
2. Make Outgoing Call Party#1 (Employee)
3. Connect Call To Party#2 (Customer)
4. (A) Party#2 Hangup Event - Prompt for survey ***-or-*** (B) when Party#1 presses some DTMF key prompt for survey

I'm stumped to if it is even possible to enable the first called party to bring up an in-call menu. I don't believe I can use the conference function as I can only make an outgoing call to the `{{contact.channel.address}}`

If using TwilML It would look something like this, is this possible?

```
<Response>
<Dial hangupOnStar="true">
    <Conference>example</Conference>
</Dial>
<Gather action="/redirectIntoConference?name=example" numDigits="1"></Gather>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option, is to use your Twiml snippet which I think came from this [post](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/twiml-redirect), but after the * give the Employee the option to transfer the Customer into the survey. For example, "Press 1 to transfer the Customer to the survey or Press 2 to take the survey yourself."

Studio Flow could then branch off the 1 or 2 from the Gather response.

You will then wire up Studio Flow to redirect the Customer's leg of the call into the survey when the Employee presses 1. You may need a custom function to do this if the Redirect Widget doesn't produce the response you are wanting. You will need to redirect the SID for the Customer's original Voicecall (aka the Conference Participant).

Your Twiml can return to the Studio Flow using these [instructions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/twiml-redirect):

```
<Response>
  <Say>Returning you back to the Studio Flow.</Say>
  <Redirect>https://webhooks.twilio.com/v1/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Flows/{FlowSid}?FlowEvent=return&amp;foo=bar</Redirect>
</Response>
```

Comment: If using the connect caller to X widget the options are only caller ended or connected call ended. 

I tried wiring up to a conference but cannot figure out how to ring the customer once the agent is connected to the conference. Studio limits the outgoing call to the TO param of the flow

Comment: @DDulla, use the Redirect widget. My experience with Studio Flow is that eventually custom functions were needed. You might have to write your own function to either use the REST Api and modify the call or return the Twiml that you want.

Comment: is the restriction on dialing the To number imposed by the widget or flow in general? In other terms if I wire up a custom function will it let me dial whoever I please?

Comment: The Make Outgoing Call widget restricts the Number to Call. But, the Connect Call To widget does not. And yes, if you wire up a custom function you could dial whomever you please but there are restrictions on the outgoing caller id.